# issue adding layer around a circular view's border

Tags: ios, view, calayer, uibezierpath

I am adding a circular layer around my circular view and setting its `position` to be the center of the view but the layer gets added at a different position. The following is the code.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    let outerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.layer.addSublayer(outerLayer)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        let outerLayerFrame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -5.0, dy: -5.0)
        outerLayer.frame = outerLayerFrame
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: outerLayerFrame)
        outerLayer.path = path.cgPath
        outerLayer.position = self.center

        outerLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        outerLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        outerLayer.lineWidth = 3
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set your layer(s) properties when the view is instantiated / initialized, but its size can (and usually does) change between then and when auto-layout adjusts it to the current device dimensions.

Unlike the `UIView` itself, layers do not auto-resize.

So, you want to set framing and layer paths in `layoutSubviews()`:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    let outerLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    // layoutSubviews is where you want to set your size
    //  and corner radius values
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // make self "round"
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2

        // add a round path for outer layer
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)
        outerLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        
        // setup layer properties here
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        outerLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        outerLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        outerLayer.lineWidth = 3
        
        // add the sublayer here
        self.layer.addSublayer(outerLayer)

    }
    
}
```

Result (with the view set to 120 x 120 pts):

[image]

Comment: I know, I only supposed to do the frame and bounds related changes in layoutSubviews. I just had it in one place to figure out my issue. However, after seeing your code, I realised that I never had to specify the position. Setting the bounds would be enough. Thank you for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized, it's the position that is making the layer not aligned in center.

Here is the solution, I figured-

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    let outerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.layer.addSublayer(outerLayer)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        let outerLayerBounds = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -5.0, dy: -5.0)
        outerLayer.bounds = outerLayerBounds // should be bounds not frame
      
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: outerLayerBounds)
        outerLayer.path = path.cgPath
        outerLayer.position = CGPoint(x: outerLayerBounds.midX , y: outerLayerBounds.midY) //self.center doesn't center the layer, had to calculate the center of the layer manually

        outerLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        outerLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        outerLayer.lineWidth = 3
    }
   
}
```